# Rotate framebuffer works only with 180° and 0°

Tags: rotation, yocto, framebuffer, screen-rotation

I'm trying to rotate the framebuffer on my Yocto machine (version 1.7.3) because I need to use the its related display in portrait mode.

I followed theese commands:

```
cd /sys/class/graphics/fb0
echo 1 > rotate
```

the result is that my framebuffer is 180° rotated.
I also tried with other parameters but, except for 1, the result is that framebuffer is alway 0°.

Does anyone faced up this problem?

Thanks in advance,

Andrea